# vkQueueSubmit causing segfault

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

In the last couple of days I have started creating a game engine in vulkan but when calling vkQueueSubmit, the program just gives me a Segmentation Fault. i have looked through the code multiple times and I can't find the reason why the segfault occures.

I would be very glad if someone can help me out. The code where vkQueueSubmit is called is [here: Window.cpp](https://github.com/ClemensU42/VoxelGame/blob/40fc458c28a5316f165715f4c4c831e239e8e9ea/src/GameEngine/Renderer/Window.cpp#L448)

Edit:
the printed info is:

```
available extensions:
    VK_KHR_device_group_creation
    VK_KHR_display
    VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities
    VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities
    VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities
    VK_KHR_get_display_properties2
    VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2
    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2
    VK_KHR_surface
    VK_KHR_surface_protected_capabilities
    VK_KHR_wayland_surface
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface
    VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display
    VK_EXT_debug_report
    VK_EXT_direct_mode_display
    VK_EXT_display_surface_counter
    VK_EXT_debug_utils
validation layers enabled!
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and the return code is 0

The call stack when the exception is this:

```
libvulkan_lvp.so![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] (Unknown Source:0)
libpthread.so.0!start_thread(void * arg) (/build/glibc-sMfBJT/glibc-2.31/nptl/pthread_create.c:477)
libc.so.6!clone() (/build/glibc-sMfBJT/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95)
```

Comment: Please add some more information. What error code is returned? Do you get any validation layer messages?

Comment: This is all that is returned:
available extensions:
 VK_KHR_device_group_creation
 ...
 VK_EXT_debug_report
 VK_EXT_direct_mode_display
 VK_EXT_display_surface_counter
 VK_EXT_debug_utils
validation layers enabled!
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
and the exit code is 0

Comment: Does your application actually have a debug callback? If not, you need to add one to get validation messages.

Comment: I have now added a debug callback but there's still no other information

Comment: That's odd. Where does the segfault occur? Inside the ICD or your app? Do you have a callstack?

Comment: I just added the callstack when the exception occurs

Comment: A non-conformant driver can behave in non-conformant ways... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Make a minimal complete example and we can get to the bottom of this...